# How to add keyboard edit support to ComboBoxTableCell

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tableview

`ComboBoxTableCell` allows to add a `ComboBox` to a `TableCell` in edit mode. If `comboBox.show()` was called (e.g. the popup is showing) the `comboBox` reacts on arrow-down and arrow-up keys pressed as expected and ends the edit mode as soon as enter is hit. I want to control the editing using only the keyboard. I was unable to find a way to get 'comboBox.show()` called using the keyboard.

Until now I tried to use `setOnKeyPressed` to add a callback to the `ComboBoxTableCell` (during creation by the factory method) or the `ComboBox` (by using `ComboBoxTableCell.getGraphic()`). The callback called `ComboBox.show()` to open the popup, but they were not called (verified by prints to `System.out` in the callback).

```
actColumn.setCellFactory(
        new Callback<TableColumn<S,Object>, TableCell<S,Object>>() {
    private ObservableList<Object> list=optionList;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public TableCell<S, Object> call(TableColumn<S, Object> param) {
        final ComboBoxTableCell<S,Object> cell=
                new ComboBoxTableCell<S,Object>(list);
        cell.setConverter((StringConverter<Object>) converter);
        cell.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            cell.startEdit();

            Node node=cell.getGraphic();
            System.out.println(node);
            if(node instanceof ComboBox) {
                System.out.println("Hit Key.");
                final ComboBox<?> box=(ComboBox<?>) node;
                box.show();
            }
        });
        //We have to forcefully fill the combobox member and set the
        //graphic, because the cell does not init the ComboBox in 
                    //its constructor
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                cell.startEdit();

                Node node=cell.getGraphic();
                if(node instanceof ComboBox) {
                    ComboBox<?> box=(ComboBox<?>) node;
                    //Now we should have the combobox for this cell
                    box.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                        System.out.println("Hit Key.");
                        if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.DOWN) {
                            System.out.println("Hit Arrow.");
                            box.show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //Stop editing again
                cell.cancelEdit();
             }
        });

        return cell;
    }
});
```

Beside this code being quite strange the handlers are not called when a key is hit in edit mode on the cell (or at least I get no output).

I want to be able to select a `ComboBoxTableCell`, hit enter (and possible one additional key) and then the popup of the internal `ComboBox` should show up without any interaction done by the mouse.

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: @Slaw Hi, Version 11.0.2.

Comment: _(You deleted your comment to my answer, this was my response):_ The problem of pressing ENTER not committing the value is actually what most of the code in my answer is solving. I considered using an `onHiding`/`onHidden` handler but decided the semantics didn't make sense; what happens if the user clicks away from the `ComboBox`? I believe that would cause the edit to be committed when it should in fact be cancelled (though I haven't tried it).

Comment: @Slaw I deleted it because I hit the problem you just noted.

Comment: Should be reported as bug, no? [bugs.openjdk.java.net](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8266228?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20component%20%3D%20javafx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass `ComboBoxTableCell` to add the behavior you want. Here's a *proof-of-concept*:

```
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class AutoShowComboBoxTableCell<S, T> extends ComboBoxTableCell<S, T> {

    /* 
     * May want to provide alternate constructors and static methods similar to
     * the ComboBoxTableCell class (i.e. the superclass).
     */

    private boolean enterPressed;

    public AutoShowComboBoxTableCell(StringConverter<T> converter, ObservableList<T> values) {
        super(converter, values);
        getStyleClass().add("auto-show-combo-box-table-cell");

        // Assumes TableView property is set only once (valid assumption?)
        tableViewProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                // Need to know if editing was started by the user pressing
                // the ENTER key (see #startEdit())
                EventHandler<KeyEvent> filter = event -> {
                    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                        enterPressed = event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED;
                    }
                };
                // Possible memory leak? Consider using WeakEventHandler (read docs)
                getTableView().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, filter);
                getTableView().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, filter);
                observable.removeListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (isEditing()) return;

        super.startEdit();
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (enterPressed) {
                // Cell was put into edit mode by the user pressing ENTER. This causes
                // problems since *releasing* ENTER while the ComboBox has the focus
                // results in the value being committed; this leads to the current value
                // being committed *immediately* after entering edit mode—not what we want. 
                // To fix that we consume the first ENTER-released event and then let all
                // subsequent events through (by removing the event filter).
                addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<>() {
                    @Override public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                            event.consume();
                            removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, this);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            ComboBox<?> comboBox = (ComboBox<?>) getGraphic();
            comboBox.requestFocus(); // Needed to allow releasing ENTER to commit the value
            comboBox.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        if (isEditing()) {
            super.cancelEdit();
            requestTableViewFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(T newValue) {
        if (isEditing()) {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
            requestTableViewFocus();
        }
    }

    // Allows user to keep navigating the table via the keyboard
    private void requestTableViewFocus() {
        TableView<S> tableView = getTableView();
        if (tableView != null) {
            tableView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

}
```

***Note:** The above uses knowledge of implementation details, both the fact the graphic is set to the `ComboBox` when the edit is started and regarding what causes the edit to be committed. Implementation details can change without notice.*

Comment: Great work!!! congratulations.